# readr not working for merging multiple .csv files together

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

I recently updated all my packages, including readr(). I am trying to merge together multiple of the same formatted .csv files from a folder into R.

Here is the code I am using:

```
df <- list.files(path = "file path here",  # Identify all CSV files
                   pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
                   lapply(read_csv) %>%                                           
                   bind_rows
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : attempt to apply non-function
In addition: Warning message:
One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details
```

Has anyone experienced this or knows a work around? I have reinstalled R and reloaded all packages and it's still not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Same as this https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1371 ?

Comment: Try using vroom instead?

Comment: Yes, I've had this happen recently. As @AdamQuek noted, that thread seems related. I've had success re-installing "cli" and "readr" packages and making sure all packages were updated.

Comment: Thanks everyone I reinstalled 'cli' and that worked! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the error is definitely coming from your use of `read_csv`. You can just use the base R version of `read.csv` instead:

```
df <- list.files(path = "file path here",  # Identify all CSV files
                   pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
                   lapply(read.csv) %>%                                           
                   bind_rows()
```